# template casting operator, 'const' keyword required

Tags: c++, templates, casting, constants

I have a template class, called `OneCell`, here the definition:

```
template <class T>
class OneCell
{
.....
}
```

I have a cast operator from `OneCell` to T, here

```
operator T() const
{
    getterCount++;
    return value;
}
```

As you see, I want to increment variable in this method, but i get an error because the keyword `const`.

On the other hand, if I remove this keyword, the casting doesn't work at all.

What can I do?

Thank you, and sorry about my poor English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `operator T() const` is a *const-member* function, inside which `this` pointer refers to a `const` object, which in turns makes the *getterCount* `const` as well.

The solution is to declare `getterCount` as mutable, as shown below:

```
mutable size_t getterCount;
```

Now `getterCount` can be incremented in const member function, which also means, it can be incremented even if the object is `const`:

```
void f(OneCell const & cell)
{
    //incrementing getterCount!
    ++cell.getterCount; //ok, even though cell is const!
}
```

Comment: But why does `operator T()` need to be `const`?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas perhaps the object he's converting is const? He doesn't show where he uses it.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: So that even `const` object can invoke it?

Answer (score 3):

> As you see, I want to increment variable in this method, but i get an error because the keyword const. On the other hand, if I remove this keyword, the casting doesn't work at all.

It will work, but only on mutable instances of `OneCell`.

> What can I do?

Go `mutable`, assuming that you change the *bitwise constness* but not the *logical constness*.

```
mutable int getterCount;
```